# C preprocessor declaration with call to free function

Tags: c

I am reading the fifth edition of a reference manual from 2002 and am very curious about the preprocessor declarations shown in a code sample. More specifically, why is it apparently necessary to add an 'x' after the call to 'free(x)'?

```
//1//#define free(x)x ? free(x) : NULL //OK 

//2//#define free(x) ? free(x) :NULL // Error

int main() {

int *p;
*p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
free(p);  // 2 -(error) ->expected a decleration

//and also see this error in both
//  ':' cannot convert from 'void *' to 'void'
```

Comment: It isn't a "call" it is a macro which is expanded at compile time. The `x` in version 1 is part of the macro expansion. In version 2 there is a syntax error because there is nothing before the `?` of the ternary expression. It's odd, because passing `NULL` to the library function `free` is benign anyway.

Comment: Using that macro would cause undefined behavior, because the second operand to the `?:` operator is a void type while the third operand isn't.

Comment: Note that you have undefined behavior cause you are dereferencing (and assigning) uninitialized pointer. `int *p; *p = ...` Probably you meant   `int *p; p = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preprocessor does straight text replacement. Without the x, your processed code would look like:

```
*p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
 ? free(p) :NUL;
```

Which is of course an error. The first example with the x would expand to

```
*p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
p ? free(p) :NUL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much